# The set of zero-square elements in a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I:=\left\{x \in R : x^2=0 \right\}$. Prove that $I$ is an ideal in $R$ or give a counterexample.

Remark: This is [problem 3B](http://math.arizona.edu/gradprogram/handbook/phdrequirements/past_quals) in the January 2003 Algebra Qualifying Examination at Arizona State University.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k$ be a ring of characteristic different from $2$ and consider the ring $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$. Then both $x,y\in I$, but $2xy$ is nonzero, so $x+y\notin I$.

Comment: This is some sort of universal example. There are also more concrete/natural examples, even for $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for appropriate $n$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I cannot see why $\mathbb Z/(n)$ would work for any $n$. For, write $n=ab^2$ with $a$ squarefree. If $x^2\in(n)$, then $ab^2|x^2$, so $ab|x$. Hence $I\subset\mathbb Z/(n)$ is the image of $(ab)$, right?